# SQL Server 2008 - DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is an example of some data

```
id  CurrentMailPromoDate
1   1/1/2013
2   3/1/2013
3   6/9/2013
4   6/10/2013
5   9/18/2013
6   12/27/2013
7   12/27/2013
```

What I need is to extract only those id's where the date diff between the current and previous record >= 100

In other words the result set would be :

```
id  CurrentMailPromoDate    
1   1/1/2013      **initial record**
3   6/9/2013    
5   9/18/2013   
6   12/27/2013  
7   12/27/2013
```

Comment: Why is id = 7 included on the results?  Also, if you had data that was on the first of every month, then you would never include subsequent records because the difference would never be more than 31, right?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is getting the previous date.  In SQL Server 2012, you can use `lag()`, but this is not supported in SQL Server 2008.  Instead, I use a correlated subquery to get the previous date.

The following returns the set you are looking for:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, CAST('2013-01-01' as DATE) as CurrentMailPromoDate union all
      select 2, '2013-03-01' union all
      select 3, '2013-06-09' union all
      select 4, '2013-06-10' union all
      select 5, '2013-09-18' union all
      select 6, '2013-12-27' union all
      select 7, '2013-12-27')
select t.id, t.CurrentMailPromoDate
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 CurrentMailPromoDate
              from t t2
              where t2.CurrentMailPromoDate < t.CurrentMailPromoDate
              order by CurrentMailPromoDate desc
             ) as prevDate
      from t
     ) t
where DATEDIFF(dd, prevDate, CurrentMailPromoDate) >= 100 or prevDate is null;
```

EDIT:

The subquery is returning the previous date for each record.  For a given record, it is looking at all the dates less than the date on the record.  These are sorted in descending order and the first one is picked.  This is `prevDate`.

The `where` clause just filters out anything that is less than 100 days from the previous date.

Comment: thanks for all your help. Would it be possible to include a brief breakdown of what the code is doing?

Comment: Assuming that the ID is replaced with an account NO. how would I go about obtaining the same results but at and account level basis. I have pasted some dummy data below 
MyronAcctNo CurrentMailPromoDate
256311   2013-01-28
256311   2013-07-01
256311   2013-08-05
2925595 2012-12-10
2925595 2013-03-25
2925595 2013-04-02
2925595 2013-04-08
2925595 2013-04-15
2925595 2013-04-22
2925595 2013-04-29
2925595 2013-05-06
2925595 2013-05-21
2925595 2013-05-27
2925595 2013-05-28
2925595 2013-06-03
2925595 2013-06-10
2925595 2013-06-17
2925595 2013-06-24

Comment: @user2596890 . . . You would include the line `t2.AccountId = t.AccountId and` in the `where` clause for the subquery.

Comment: I did just that and it worked....however the problem I am having is trying to understand why the query work's as pasted below but does not when I included the COMMENTED OUT DATES AND EXCLUDE those that work...code is below

Comment: this is the code for the temp table creation. it is the value that are commented that do not work. 
select 256311 as id, '2013-01-28' CurrentMailPromoDate into #test union all
    --select 256311, '2013-02-18' union all
    --  select 256311, '2013-02-25' union all
      select 256311, '2013-03-01' union all
   --   select 256311, '2013-04-02' union all
      select 256311, '2013-06-09' union all
      select 256311, '2013-06-10' union all
    --  select 256311, '2013-07-01' union all
    --  select 256311, '2013-08-05' union all
      select 256311, '2013-12-27';

Comment: THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT OF THE WHERE CONDITION....IT HAD TO BE DONE BY ACCOUNT NO AS WELL AS COMPANY CODE SINCE THIS IS A GLOBAL REPORT    where t2.CurrentMailPromoDate < t.CurrentMailPromoDate and
     t2.MyronCoCode=t.MyronCoCoCode and
     t2.MyronAcctNo=t.MyronAcctNo

Comment: Please ignore my previous comments.

Comment: @user2596890 . . .Two things.  You can actually delete your comments.  If you hover the mouse in the right spot, there is a little, faint "x" by the time.  Clicking on it deletes the comments.  Also, code samples work much better in a question or answer.  It is better to edit the question, place the indicator "EDIT", along with some explanation, and the formatted code.